# Does not contain a definition for 'HasAlternateKey' (EF 6, Code-First, VS2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Hi everyone this is my first question so i will do my best.
The past few weeks I have been exploring the Entity Framework and the uses for database programming, using Code-First.

Now I'm trying to incorporate the Alternate Keys to my model, I though that it was enough making a column an Index and Uniqueness but it wasn't enought for making them a FK from another table.

I found a way to declare AK using the Fluent API that is very simple but when I tryied to use it;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TypeBus>().HasAlternateKey(c => c.buscode)
```

but Visual Studio says: EntityTypeConfiguration < TypeBus > does not contain a definition for 'HasAlternateKey' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeConfiguration< TypeBus >' could be found.

This is my piece of code summarized:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Example_Bus.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Example_Bus.DAL
{
public class SystemContext : DbContext
{

    public SystemContext() : base("SystemContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TypeBus> TypeBuses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Update(u => u.HasName("modify_student")));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Venedor>().Property(e => e.personaId).HasColumnName("venedorId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bus>().MapToStoredProcedures();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Conductor>().MapToStoredProcedures();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TypeBus>().HasAlternateKey(c => c.buscode);

    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing a "using" or something but I couldn't find anything anywhere.
I will appreciate any help ^^
Thanks you.

Comment: Probably you are looking at EF Core documentation. There is no alternate key support in EF6.

Comment: What is the difference between EF core and EF6? I didn't know that exists this two variations.

Comment: Huuuge. You could start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)

Comment: I mean for what different purposes are they used, in general. For have an idea of which one i should use. If i have a project with EF6 will work with EF core?
Thanks for all the help btw :)

Comment: I wouldn't say they are used for different purposes. EF Core is a redesign/rewrite, hence is the future of Entity Framework. From the other side, it lacks some of the EF6 features and has more bugs, but is actively developed (fixing, extending), has shorter release timeframes and some things not supported in EF6 (like alternate keys in question). EF6 and EF Core are not compatible in many regards and require porting. But all this is explaned (sort of) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for help me to understand it and make me earn so much time looking for it

Comment: Note that EF6 supports Unique Indexes, but doesn't support foreign keys that reference unique indexes.  EF Core does.

Answer (score -1):

You can create Unique indexes. Works the same as Alternate keys.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourTable>().HasIndex(x => new { x.AKField1, x.AKField2 }).IsUnique();

modelBuilder.Entity<esc20_GrupoClase>().HasIndex(x => new { x.clase_uid, x.grupo_uid }).IsUnique();
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Unique index can't be the target of foreign key relationship because EF6 doesn't support it.